# php code deprecated error on php 7.1 preg_replace

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$cityval        = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $cityval);               
$serial_extra  = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $serial_extra);               
$serial_extra  = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $serial_extra);
```

I was using PHP 5.6 version, once I upgrade it to 7.1 version it shows an error "code deprecated". Please suggest me any better replacement of this code

Comment: Its deprecated, that mean you have until you move to 7.2 at least to find your own solution

Comment: A useful read, before moving versions of PHP is the Deprecation notices https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php

Comment: And before you move again https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.deprecated.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php